# How to compare dates in ISO8601 format?

Tags: java, date, iso8601

Is there a way to compare ISO8601 dates with Java? Like, to know if the String date is the good format, to know if months are not negative and not >12, to know if days are not over 31, when %4 if february doesn't have over 29 days...

I'm also searching how to know if there is a class on the Internet to compare two ISO8601 dates? Like, if I have: 2000-12-12 and 1999-05-06. How can I compare those two dates to have the exact difference between years, months and days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to compare ISO8601 dates with Java? Like, to know if
> the String date is the good format, to know if months are not negative
> and not >12, to know if days are not over 31, when %4 if february
> doesn't have over 29 days...

Get a `LocalDate` instance on passing the year, the month and the day of the month as parameters to [LocalDate.of](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#of-int-int-int-) inside a `try-catch` block. If any of these will be invalid, `DateTimeException` will be thrown indicating the same.

## Demo

```
import java.time.DateTimeException;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int year, month, dayOfMonth;
        LocalDate date;
        System.out.print("Enter the year, month and day separated by space: ");
        year = scanner.nextInt();
        month = scanner.nextInt();
        dayOfMonth = scanner.nextInt();

        try {
            date = LocalDate.of(year, month, dayOfMonth);
            System.out.println("The date in ISO 8601 format is " + date);
        } catch (DateTimeException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Enter the year, month and day separated by space: 2020 2 30
Invalid date 'FEBRUARY 30'
```

**Another sample run:**

```
Enter the year, month and day separated by space: 2020 2 29
The date in ISO 8601 format is 2020-02-29
```

> I'm also searching how to know if there is a class on the Internet to
> compare two ISO8601 dates? Like, if I have: 2000-12-12 and 1999-05-06.
> How can I compare those two dates to have the exact difference between
> years, months and days?

Use [LocalDate#until](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#until-java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDate-) to get `java.time.Period` from which you can get years, months and days.

## Demo

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Period;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String dateStr1 = "1999-05-06";
        String dateStr2 = "2000-12-12";

        LocalDate date1 = LocalDate.parse(dateStr1);
        LocalDate date2 = LocalDate.parse(dateStr2);

        Period period = date1.until(date2);
        System.out.printf("There are %d years, %d months and %d days between %s and %s", period.getYears(),
                period.getMonths(), period.getDays(), dateStr1, dateStr2);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
There are 1 years, 7 months and 6 days between 1999-05-06 and 2000-12-12
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just one question, Period period is a type Period, so I can't use < and > because it is not an Integer. What can I do?

Comment: You are most welcome. `period.getYears()` returns an `int` which you can use with arithmetic operators. Similar is the case with `getMonths()`, `getDays()` etc. I recommend you go through [this tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/period.html) to learn more about it.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Java 8 or newer, use the facilities in the `java.time` package:

```
LocalDate date1 = LocalDate.parse("1999-05-06"), 
    date2 = LocalDate.parse("2000-12-12");
Period period = Period.between(date1, date2);
// Prints "1 years, 7 months and 6 days"
System.out.printf("%d years, %d months and %d days\n", period.getYears(),
            period.getMonths(), period.getDays());
```

All the information you need can be extracted from the methods in the `LocalDate` class. If the string is in an invalid format, the `LocalDate::parse` method will throw an exception indicating what's wrong.

Comment: Oh thanks! Gonna see that! Yes I use JDK14. And, do you know an Exception class that verifies all that I mentionned in the post :O ? I created mine but I'm sure that it already exsist no?

Comment: You don't need to code any of this stuff. It's already handled by the `parse` method, which will throw a `DateTimeParseException` with the cause of failure in the message.

Answer (score 1):

Some examples on how to parse and compare dates in Java (8+). You can use the `java.time.LocalDate` class for that. Here the examples:

```
try {
    LocalDate.of(2000, 13, 12);
} catch (DateTimeException e) {
    System.out.println("It seems the date 12/13/2000 is invalid?");
}

// If you have only a string...

LocalDate.parse("2000-03-10");
System.out.println("I managed to parse the date from a string");

try {
    LocalDate.of(2000, 2, 30);
} catch (DateTimeException e) {
    System.out.println("It seems the date 30/02/2000 is invalid?");
}

var date1 = LocalDate.of(2000, 12, 12);
var date2 = LocalDate.of(1999, 5, 6);

if (date1.isBefore(date2)) {
    System.out.println("Date 1 is before date 2");
} else if (date1.isEqual(date2)) {
    System.out.println("Date 1 is equal to date 2");
} else {
    System.out.println("Date 1 is after date 2");
}

var period = Period.between(date2, date1);

System.out.println("Difference between date 1 and date 2 is: ");
System.out.print(period.getYears() + " years, ");
System.out.print(period.getMonths() + " months, ");
System.out.print(period.getDays() + " days");
```

This would print:

```
It seems the date 12/13/2000 is invalid?
I managed to parse the date from a string
It seems the date 30/02/2000 is invalid?
Date 1 is after date 2
Difference between date 1 and date 2 is: 
1 years, 7 months, 6 days
```

If you have to deal with times too, you can use the `LocalDateTime` class. Both classes will save you a lot of time if you were trying to do it manually!

You can also calculate the distance in days using the `ChronoUnit` class, by simply doing this:

```
ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(date1, date2);
ChronoUnit.MONTHS.between(date1, date2);
ChronoUnit.YEARS.between(date1, date2);
```

Have a look at the ChronoUnit methods here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html

Comment: thanks a lot! Do you know how to convert a Period into an Int?

Comment: an int, meaning the total number of days? months? years?

Comment: In any case, you can get the number of days using the `ChronoUnit` class in Java: `ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(date1, date2);`

Comment: Yeah!
I want something that can make: .between(LocalDate.parse(date), LocalDate.now() and gives the answer with an Integer :D

Comment: You can do that, as I explained. Anyway, I've updated the answer, hope it helps you!

Comment: Helped a lot!! Thanks for the info :D

Comment: just one last thing, do you know whats the difference between LocalDateParseException and LocalDateException :O ?

Comment: `DateTimeParseException` is raised when there's an error parsing a String to a LocalDate instance. When using `LocalDate.parse()` this exception could be raised, as you can see here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-. `DateTimeException` is raised when the date parts are incorrect, as I showed you on the examples above.